# Change just one status bar with Android and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on a project with Android and Jetpack Compose and I want to change the status bar color for just one view and the rest of them keeping with the assigned color.

How can I do this with Jetpack Compose? Is there a way to have more than one color in the status bar?

Comment: Can't you use https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/?

Comment: Or do you mean to have two colors at the same time?

Comment: @kingston hey, the idea is having different colors for each screen. For example, in the screen A using red color and for screen B using black color. is it possible? With screens I mean different Activities. Right now the color of the status bar is defined with the theme palette of the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it following the doc [here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/).
You can update the system bar colors like so:

```
// Remember a SystemUiController
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
val useDarkIcons = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight

SideEffect {
    // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
    // dark icons if we're in light theme
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = useDarkIcons
    )
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. Thanks!!

Comment: how to undo it if i navigate to another view?

Comment: this library is deprecated